# Cannot reshape array of size 12288 into shape (64,64)

Tags: numpy, image-preprocessing

I have an image I loaded with the `image.load_img()` function but when I try to reshape it I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12288 into shape (64,64)
```

Here is my code:

```
test_image = image.load_img('xray_dataset_covid19/test/PNEUMONIA/streptococcus-pneumoniae-pneumonia-temporal-evolution-1-day2.jpg'
                            , target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
if result[0][0] == 1:
    img = Image.fromarray(test_image.reshape(64,64) ,'L')
    img.show()
```

Comment: For future questions: the key information that would have helped in the question (that I found in comments below) was the output of `test_image.shape`. Also I have assumed you were using the PIL library: it helps to show all your imports at the top of the code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is even better!

Answer (score 3):

$64\times 64 = 4096$. You're short about $8000$ pixels.

Comment: If you have a third dimension, say RGB images, with three layers of $64\times 64$, you wind up with the desired number of pixels. I suspect your bug is something like that.

Comment: i get this : ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.

Comment: I don't follow your Python code well enough to be able to diagnose much further, but perhaps your method calls expect 2-tensors (e.g., black and white images) instead of 3-tensors (e.g., RGB images).

Comment: when I ```print(test_image.shape)``` I get ```(1, 64, 64, 3)```

Answer (score 0):

> when I print(test_image.shape) I get (1, 64, 64, 3)

What you probably wanted was:

```
if result[0][0] == 1:
    img = Image.fromarray(test_image.reshape(64,64,3))
    img.show()
```

I.e. specify the `,3`, because you have RGB data, and drop the `,'L'` because [that means](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) you have B/W data.

If you actually wanted greyscale or b/w change the last line to one of:

```
img.convert('L').show()
img.convert('1').show()
```

Stepping back a bit, you could have used `test_image` directly, and not needed to reshape it, except it was in a batch of size 1. A better way to deal with it, and not have to explicitly state the image dimensions, is:

```
if result[0][0] == 1:
    img = Image.fromarray(test_image.squeeze(0))
    img.show()
```

`squeeze()` removes any dimensions of size 1; `squeeze(0)` avoids surprises by being more specific: if the first dimension is of size 1 remove it, otherwise do nothing.

Yet another way to do it, that ties in with how you use `result`, is:

```
if result[0][0] == 1:
    img = Image.fromarray(test_image[0])
    img.show()
```